# Error C2893 Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::equal_to<void>::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) noexcept(<expr>) const'

Tags: c++

I use template to create two class called `bag` and `linked_list`. And I write a function called `find` as a member of bag class. This function is create to find the position of elements in bag class.

I have already overload the `operator==` of the class `ThreeD` and `linked_list`. I declare a element pointer `item<linked_list<ThreeD<double>>>* p` and the `find` function run correctly.

But when it comes to another element `item<list<linked_list<ThreeD<int>>>>* p20`, the program crush then had an error 2893.  Why does this happen?

`ThreeD` class:

```
template <class T> class ThreeD {
public:
    T ht;
    T wid;
    T dep;
    ThreeD() { ht = wid = dep = 0; }
    ThreeD(T i) { ht = wid = dep = i; }
    ThreeD(T a, T b, T c) { ht = a; wid = b; dep = c; }
    T getVol() { return ht * wid * dep; }
    //two objects are equal if their getVol() return the same value.
    bool operator==(ThreeD<T>& t1) {
        if (getVol() == t1.getVol()) {
            return true;
        }
        else { return false; }
    }

    bool operator!=(ThreeD<T>& t1) {
        if (getVol() == t1.getVol()) {
            return false;
        }
        else { return true; }
    }
};
```

`operator==` for `linked_list` class:

```
bool operator==(linked_list& L) {
        node<T>* it1 = head;
        node<T>* it2 = L.head;
        int count1 = 0;
        while (it1 != nullptr) {
            count1++;
            it1 = it1->next;
        }
        int count2 = 0;
        while (it2 != nullptr) {
            count2++;
            it2 = it2->next;
        }
        if (count1 != count2) { return false; }
        else {
            it1 = head;
            it2 = L.head;
            while (it1 != nullptr && it2 != nullptr) {
                if (it1->value != it2->value) { return false; }
                it1 = it1->next;
                it2 = it2->next;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

`main` function:

```
int main(){
item<linked_list<ThreeD<double>>>* p2;
    p2 = BLTD.find(LTD1);

item<list<linked_list<ThreeD<int>>>>* p20 = B16.find(V4);
    if (p20 != nullptr) cout << (p20->data).size() << endl;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: change `bool operator==(ThreeD<T>& t1) ` to `bool operator==(const ThreeD<T>& t1) const` and similarly for `!=`

Comment: It works. So it is necessary to keep the operator function a const?